# Is there a way of joining list using some criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to join different lists that have less than 3 values on it, there is an example

[image: here].

I was able to do it using macros, but I wanted something more automated because these lists updated quite often, is there a way of doing something like that just by using formulas? If no, is there a way of doing it using VBA but in a better way than "clicking" buttons?

Answering VBasic2008:

I am new to this intermediary/advanced excel functions. I just realized that my Macro didn't work. It does not matter where the results will be, could just be at the end of the table. I have around 20 columns.
Basically, I tried to make something that checks if the number of values in the column is below 3 and if it is it would take this list and paste on the "Group X", but I am trying to use just functions to do that, I was able to make a list with all the columns using INDEX + MOD, but it took all of the names, from AAA to the last one, and I wanted something that would take just the list with less than 3 values.

Some update:

> =INDEX(IF($F$11:$J$11=3;$F$6:$J$9;"");MOD(ROW()-ROW($O$6);4)+1;INT((ROW()-ROW($O$6))/4)+1)

I was able to come up with this formula, but everything appears with some spaces. [image: formula]

Thanks,
Matheus

Comment: How many columns are you expecting? Will there be an empty column between the columns and the result? Will the result be in the same worksheet? Share a little more information. Could you share your previous macro so we could get a better feel of what your trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this with formulas is possible, but quite advanced. Someone here will write a formula for you which you may not be able to maintain when your scenario changes.

If you already have VBA code that does what you need doing, then you can move that code to an event procedure that starts automatically when a new value is added to the columns.

The event you need is the `Worksheet_Change` event and it lives in the Sheet module (right-click the sheet and click "View Code". That will show the Sheet module.

In your scenario, you want to run the code when a value is changed in columns D to G, so your code must start with something like

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

' run only when a value in columns D to G are changed
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:G")) Is Nothing Then

    ' your code goes here
    MsgBox "You just changed a value in one of the the watched columns!"

End If

End Sub
```

**Edit after additional requirements**

If you have Office 365 with the new Dynamic Array functions, this formula approach will work.
Building on your index formula, I made a small change. You can use the modified index formula in a helper column. Then use the Filter() function on the values returned by the Index formulas.

[image]

Index formula in cell J4 and copied down to J23

`=INDEX(IF($D$11:$H$11=3,$D$4:$H$7,"#"),MOD(ROW()-ROW($J$4),4)+1,INT((ROW()-ROW($J$4))/4)+1)`

Filter formula in K4

`=FILTER(J4:J23,(J4:J23<>"#")*(J4:J23<>0))`

Comment: I really want to try that with formulas (if possible, of course). I know it would be difficult to follow up with different scenarios, but I am just thinking about making everything without codes. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I added a formula approach to my answer.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the tour. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the 365, but I figured out a way of doing it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, try the following:

- I put the formula to count the number of entries in row 2, to make it easier to add items below.
- I assumed you mean three or less; and not less than three.

If you have Windows O365, you can use the following formulas: (*and change the `100` to the lowest possible row*)

```
D2:  =COUNTA(D$4:D$100)
```

and fill right for the number of columns

```
I4: =FILTERXML("<t><s>" & TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,FILTER($D$4:$G$100,$D$2:$G$2<=3)) &"</s></t>","//s")
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the 365, but I figured out a way of doing it. Thanks